# Multiple consumers are created after site recycle. RabbitMq/Masstransit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I use Masstransit in my .net web application to connect to RabbitMq.
Sometime after site recycle, I see lots of consumers on a single queue. I didn't set competing consumers and in normal situation I should have only one consumer per queue.

[image]

When this problem happens, my messages get processed very slowly (I assume the time depends on my retry policy) and I have to showdown the site and start it again.

I use Masstransit 5.2.3/RabbitMq 3.7.6.

Could anyone give any clue what the problem could be?

Comment: Where do you start and stop the bus?

Comment: I start the bus at Global.ascx Application_Start and stop it at Application_End

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I checked my application startup log, apparently multiple concurrent startup happened! I think this is due to IIS Overlapped Recycle feature. I can disable overlapped recycle, But I think of that as my last solution.

Comment: The thing is that IIS will start as many instances of your application as you configure in the app pool settings. It is quite normal to have multiple instances running, web apps are usually load-balanced. So, you will have multiple consumers but I don't really understand why is it a problem. Only one instance will get a message anyway.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem of having multiple instance of app, But as long as messages get processed quickly. My problem is that message get stuck in the queue and get processed very late.

Comment: What is your consumer doing? Those deliver/ack rates are really slow, which typically points to a poorly performing consumer. What external dependencies does your consumer need? Are they slow or bottlenecked?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson My consumers mostly need talk to database. But performance counters show db is working fine.
During last year I faced this issue a few times on my development machine, I put a breakpoint on constructor of my IConsumer class, But breakpoint hitted very late. So I deleted temporary queues and restart the app, everything worked fine again.
For further investigation, I can create a new consumer without any dependency. Do u think it would help to find reason?
Also I use Autofac 4.8.1.

Comment: Look at the detailed MassTransit logs, it should show the consumer execution times and give you an idea of what's taking so long.